# How to handle advanced Uri Patterns in Android

Tags: android, uri

Implementation of Content Provider with a complicated queries required a complex uri patterns, and i don't understand how can i handle this.

1. Can i use Regular Expression in my patterns? example: `/user/:[a-zA-Z]/timeline/` if the user must contain only letters.
2. Which symbols tells the UriMather what the parameters example: `/user/:userId/timeline/year/:yearNumber`, i would get userId and yearNumber as parameters , so how do i should get the values ? should i use `getPathSegments()` and get the parameters manually?
3. or if i used `/user/#/timeline/year/#` how do i extract the # values

Answer (score 0):

By using the format `/user/#/timeline/year/#` you can call:

```
uri.getPathSegments().get(1); // To get the first #
uri.getPathSegments().get(4); // to get the second #
// 0 -> user, 1 -> first #, 2 -> timeline, 3 -> year, 4 -> second #
```

So in your content provider you would have something like this:

```
private static final int USER_TIMELINE_YEAR = 1;
// ...

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static
{
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "user/#/timeline/year/#", USER_TIMELINE_YEAR);
}

// Usually a ContentProvider method like query, insert, delete and update
public void someMethod(Uri uri) {
  if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == USER_TIMELINE_YEAR) {
      String userId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
      String timelineYear = uri.getPathSegments().get(4);
  }
}
```

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html

Comment: ok thank you do you know what about the first question about Regular Expression ?

Comment: No, you can't use regular expressions. You can use # for any number and * for any string.